# how to display sharepoint online 2013 files/Directories in a separate silverlight 5 web Application

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-documents

I want to show a list of files from sharepoint online 2013 in silverlight 5 in a separate web application. Is there any way to achieve it?

I have tried following ways, so if someone has a sample please share with me..

- using list.asmx
- using Client Object Model
- using Odata Service

Mostly I am looking to achieve it from first 2 ways.

Comment: Please someone answer on this. It would be great Help..

Thanks!

Comment: Guys please someone answer on this. 

Also i would like to know if this is possible using (Html Jquery and javascript).

Please help me out here